# Magento 2 website behaves weird when new browser (that has never visited the site) visits the site

Tags: magento2

Each time I get to my website with a browser that has never get to it, deleted modules/extensions appear, some css does not load, ecc, how can I fix that problem? The next time I go to the site, it acts normally

Comment: It looks like your store is in developer mode and in backend settings in advance=> developer=> change to server side compilation

Answer (score 0):

If you try to visit your website in incognito mode, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable Sign Static Files

> Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Sign Static Files: Yes

Run CLI command after enable Sign Static Files

```
php bin/magento set:up &&
php bin/magento c:c &&
php bin/magento c:f &&
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Hope it works for you.